# Upgraded to 10.10.4 (from 10.8.5), now JNLPs don't open in finder?

Tags: macos, finder, java

I've finally upgraded from 10.8.5 to 10.10.4. But now double clicking on a JNLP file in finder no longer downloads and runs the (in the JNLP file defined) jars but takes me to the Oracle Java download page. This despite

- JDKs 1.7/1.8 installed in /Library/Java
- as well as the Apple 1.6 installed in /System/Library/Java.

I'm doing a fair bit of Java development using the Oracle 1.7 and 1.8 JDK's installed in /Library/Java and pointed at by

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`
```

running java from the console finds the right version:

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)
```

So where/how can I tell finder to use the JDK's to open JNLPs?

EDIT: output from this command:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V


Matching Java Virtual Machines (4):
    1.8.0_25, x86_64:   "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.7.0_71, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-466.1, x86_64: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-466.1, i386:   "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Comment: What do you get if you try "/usr/libexec/java_home -V" in a Terminal window?

Comment: added to question above

Comment: What about the output of 'which javaws', where javaws is the command used to open Java WebStart files? For me on 10.10.4 with the Oracle 1.8 JDK and Apple 1.6 JDK installed, the output is '/usr/bin/javaws', which is a symlink to /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/javaws.

Comment: is javaws used to open JNLP files by the finder? mine points at the Apple javaws, which complains that there is no JRE to invoke: $ which javaws
/usr/bin/javaws
$ ll /usr/bin/javaws
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  76 29 Jun 13:38 /usr/bin/javaws -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/javaws
$ javaws
No Java runtime present, requesting install.
Unable to locate a Java Runtime to invoke.

Comment: I wonder can I just replace that symlink and point to one of Oracles JDKs?

Comment: Ah, the plot thickens. There isn't a javaws in any of the JDKs. The only javaws that seems to be symlinked out of /Library/Application Support/Oracle/Java/javaws->/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/_javaws and that does not exist. I suppose that would need to be reinstalled, probably got canned in the upgrade.